# Apply the same function multiple time with different sets of arguments

Tags: matlab, function, cell

Here is part of my function, I want to past 4 sets of data into my function `blood_type`.

In each set, one of the arguments is `numeric` and another is `character`.

For the output `Type` and `Vol`, each of them is a 3D-matrix of size `80*80*2`.

[image]

I want to have a neat way such that I can obtain an `ALL_TYPE` which is a result by concatenating 4 outputs of `blood_type` (each type is from each `patient_id` and `patient_name`).

`ALL_TYPE = cat(3, Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4)`

Similarly, I want to have

`ALL_VOL = cat(3, Vol1, Vol2, Vol3, Vol4)`

Instead of writing:

```
[Type1 Vol1] = blood_type(1, 'Ann');
[Type2 Vol2] = blood_type(2, 'Ben');
[Type3 Vol3] = blood_type(3, 'Chris');
[Type4 Vol4] = blood_type(4, 'David');
```

Are there any ways that can choose the pair of arguments and produce the outputs more efficient? It is because I have hundreds of patients and this will be cumbersome if I type hundreds of times the names and their IDs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem seems a bit odd: how would the program know what `blood_type` to ask for, if you don't give the name of the patient and its ID? Which means that you'd need to type at least once the name of the patients, and their ID. But you want to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach, using `cellfun`;

```
%'The arguments of the function need to be typed once anyways'
patient_id   = {1,2,3,4};
patient_name = {'Ann','Ben','Chris','David'};

[ALL_TYPE, ALL_VOL] = cellfun( ...
   @blood_type, patient_id, patient_name, ...
   'UniformOutput', false ...
);

ALL_TYPE = cat(3, ALL_TYPE{:});
ALL_VOL  = cat(3, ALL_VOL{:});
```

Comment: Nice and simple =) @nam: Note that although `cellfun` is neat, and easy to read and write, it's just a disguised for-loop.

Comment: @CST Thank you for your solution and @stewie Thank you for your reminder of explaining the `cellfun`.